# Interface with Generics

Tags: c#, generics

I have a Interface like this...

```
public interface IVisitsService
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetVisits<T,S>(S filters);
}
```

My Application will be using this interface for different objects. Say Class "A" and Class "B" will implement this interface, however they will supply their own objects for the "T" and "S" Generics, hence the return type and the parameter type will VARY  per object. I am having hard time to solve this issue properly.

For example...

```
public class VisitsBService : IVisitsService
{    
    public IEnumerable<T> GetVisits<T,S>(S filters)
    {
        return _visitRepo.GetVisits<VisitsHcs,VisitFilters>(filters);
    }
}
```

Then another class can use it with its own object...

```
public class VisitsAService : IVisitsService
{    
    public IEnumerable<T> GetVisits<T,S>(S filters)
    {
        return _visitRepo.GetVisits<VisitsBcs,VisitBFilters>(filters);
    }
}
```

Comment: should you make `IVisistsService` generic?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I think you meant to define the generics on the interface, and not the method `IVisitsService<T, S>`.  I'd also recommend giving them better names.  The typical way to name generics is with a capital T then a meaningful name.  Maybe `IVisitsService<TResult, TFilters>`?

Comment: how can you down vote without even reading the question. Someone with great knowledge actually answered my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make your interface generic:

```
public interface IVisitsService<T, S>
```

Then you can implement it by supplying type arguments:

```
public class VisitsBService : IVisitsService<VisitsHcs,VisitFilters>
```